# How to get the project version description in Jira via the Soap api

Tags: java, soap, jira

Does anybody know how to get the version description field for a Jira project?  Using the `ProjectService.getVersions` method we can get an Array of `RemoteVersion` objects but these `RemoteVersion` objects do not contain the description field.

[Documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/service/ProjectService.html#getVersions(com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User,%20java.lang.String)) for `ProjectService.getVersions()`:

```
getVersions
RemoteVersion[] getVersions(com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User user,
                            java.lang.String projectKey)
                            throws RemoteException
Throws:
RemoteException
```

Will I have to expose my own web service via a Jira plugin to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Atlassian support this is not possible (yet).